# iterator_adapter.hpp file not found

Tags: react-native, boost, cocoapods, folly

In our react-native app, we're using `cocoapods`. After the usual set up for a new computer, including cloning the repo, installing `node_modules` installing and updating pods, then launching the app, I get the dreaded message `Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist`.

The actual error is

```
fatal error: 'boost/iterator/iterator_adapter.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_adapter.hpp>
```

- I looked on the RN issues page. [I found this.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14404) None of the
  suggested fixes worked for me.
- No one in my department has been able to resolve this.
- I've recloned the source and reloaded/updated the pods multiple times.
- No one else but me is experiencing this issue including folks that joined with the department with me.

I have literally run out of ideas.

EDIT: I checked another app source I have and it appears that I should have a `/third-party` folder. It does not. I think that this is one of those wonky problems where the RN script doesn't complete. Any thoughts?

EDIT: After reinstalling pods and building the app in Xcode, I noticed a typo in the include statement in the `BitIteratorDetail.h` file. It reads:

`#include <boost/iterator/iterator_adaptor.hpp>`,

but the filename is actually `iterator_adapter.hpp`. However, correcting the typo did not resolve the problem. I still get a `file not found` error.

Comment: Issue resolved. I needed to delete the pod cache. Here's what I did
If you get a pod-based error, perform the following steps:
- Clear the cache: rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
- Remove the pods: rm -rf Pods
- Just to be sure, remove xcode derived data: rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
- rerun install from /ios (don't use npm script for this): in project folder run - cd ios && pod install
- clear pod cache, just in case: pod cache clean --all
- return to project root: cd..
- and run npm run ios

Comment: This worked for me, add this as an answer.